# Access value of Firebase RTDB snapshot on value

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to read the value of the snapshot.val() response. The structure of my Firebase Realtime Database looks like this:

```
example-default-rtdb
+ 1234567
++ abcdefg
+++ foo: "bar"
```

Firebase:

```
const db = firebase.database()
const ref = db.ref('1234567/')

ref.limitToLast(1).on(
  'value',
  snapshot => {
    const response = snapshot.val()
    const message = response.foo
  },
  errorObject => {
    console.log("error")
  }
)
```

`response.foo` returns *undefined* instead of *bar*. I tried JSON.parse and JSON.stringify - they all return undefined.

This the output if I use *const message =  JSON.stringify(response, null, '    ')*

```
{
    "123456": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
```

How to access the value of *foo*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't know the `abcdefg`, in which case you can use `forEach` to loop over all the child nodes of `snapshot`:

```
const db = firebase.database()
const ref = db.ref('1234567/')

ref.limitToLast(1).on(
  'value',
  snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      console.log(child.key, child.val(), child.val().foo)
    }
  },
  errorObject => {
    console.log("error")
  }
)
```